# Is order of data frames important in RNN / LSTM

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I learned from [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45765082/672018) on the internet that when processing time series with RNN or LSTM, the time series should be divided into overlapping time windows like that:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6] => [[1,2,3],[2,3,4][3,4,5][4,5,6]]
```

This was quite a surprise for me since I thought that sequence learning was kind of built into a recurrent network.

1. Does it mean the topology from above can only learn sequences of 3 elements?
2. Does it mean I can feed the time windows in random order?
3. If not, why bother splitting the sequence into time windows instead of simply feeding the net element by element?